# Combine text using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to combine text using jquery, this is my code:

```
<textarea id="input1" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:100px; resize:none;" placeholder="Text 1" wrap="off"></textarea>
<textarea id="input2" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:100px; resize:none;" placeholder="Text 2" wrap="off"></textarea>
<textarea id="input3" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:100px; resize:none;" placeholder="Text 3" wrap="off"></textarea>
<textarea id="ouput" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:100px; resize:none;" placeholder="Output" wrap="off"></textarea>
<button id="process" type="button" name="clicknow">Generate!</button>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#process').on('click', function(){
var test1 = $('#test1').val();
var test2 = $('#test2').val();
var test3 = $('#test3').val();
$('textarea#output').append(test1+test2+test3);
    });
</script>
```

Input 1:

> 1-one
>
> 2-two
>
> 3-three

Input 2:

> 4-four
>
> 5-five
>
> 6-six

Input 3:

> 7-seven
>
> 8-eight
>
> 9-nine

Ouput:

> 1-one 4-four 7-seven
>
> 2-two 5-five 8-eight
>
> 3-three 6-six 9-nine

Comment: where's the `jQuery` part

Comment: `$("#input1").val();` to get the inputted value.

Comment: @j2query, check my answer, it outputs the expected result, the challenging part for you is to make it dynamic. goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bsarunmca/2bfz5qLa/ -- Check this file.

```
$('#process').click(function(){
    $('#ouput').val($('#input1').val() + ' ' + $('#input2').val() + ' ' +  $('#input3').val());
});
```

Comment: i want the output just like my post

Answer (score 0):

This was a good programming practice. See this fiddle if it works: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5cz3rtmb/4/

I have added some JS functions to make this work:

```
$("#process").click(function() {
    var outputText = getOutput(
        $("#input1").val(),
        $("#input2").val(),
        $("#input3").val()
    );
    $("#output").html(outputText); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. just make some tweak to make it dynamic

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9eps8x06/

```
$('#process').click(function(){

    var lines1 = $('#input1').val().split('\n'); 
    var lines2 = $('#input2').val().split('\n');
    var lines3 = $('#input3').val().split('\n');
    var output=''; 

    output += lines1[0] +  lines2[0] + lines3[0]+'\n';
    output += lines1[1] +  lines2[1] + lines3[1]+'\n';
    output += lines1[2] +  lines2[2] + lines3[2]+'\n';

   $('#output').val(output); 
});
```